# importing jQuery into React - TypeError for jQuery in componentDidMount

Tags: jquery, reactjs

This is how I'm importing jQuery into React:

```
import { $, autocomplete } from "jquery";
```

I also tried

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

but no luck there either.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery.$) is not a function
```

And this is the jQuery I have in my compenentDidMount that it's complaining about:

```
  $("#loc").autocomplete({
    source: getCityData,
    select: selectCityItem,
    minLength: 3,
    change: function() {
   }
  });

$("#query").autocomplete({
   source: getQueryData,
   select: selectQueryItem,
   minLength: 2,
   change: function() {
   }
 });
```

Any ideas on how I can get rid of this error?

Comment: did you try `jQuery(...)` with the `import $ from 'jquery' ` statement?

Comment: autocomplete looks like a 3rd-pary jQuery plugin not part of jQuery. Did you also import that?

Comment: No, it is part of jQuery. This is working on an old project and they only imported jQuery

Comment: jQuery doesn't have all these exports by default, as shown here https://codesandbox.io/s/644z34zppz . So please share your custom jquery source as is, if possible, for us to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Y'all were right. Autocomplete is a widget that comes from jquery-ui, so I had to do

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js";
import "jquery-ui/themes/base/autocomplete.css";
```